# How to run a command to communicate with the Docker container started in a previous job step in Github Action?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, continuous-integration, github-actions

In order to build a *Github Action* to start a *Docker container* and then run a command, e.g. `python3 -m unittest`, which communicate with the started *Docker container*, I created a *workflow* yml file:

```
on: [push]

jobs:
  ci_test_job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: CI Test
    steps:
    - name: Start Wildfly container for integration test
      id: start-wildfly
      uses: user/dict/ci-test@master
    - name: Run Python script
      run: python3 -m unittest discover -s uat/
```

The `python3` command send http request to the Docker container started in the first step `Start Wildfly container for integration test`

The action defined in `user/dict/ci-test@master` looks like this:

```
name: 'Continuous Integration Test'
description: 'Docker Container used for integration test'
runs:
  using: 'docker'
  image: 'Dockerfile'
```

The code in the corresponding `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM jboss/wildfly:latest
RUN wildfly/bin/add-user.sh -u admin -p admin --silent
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", "-c", "standalone.xml", "-Djboss.http.port=8080", "-Djboss.management.http.port=9998", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0"]
```

**Problem:** When I push the code to Github, the Docker image is built successfully, but it never reaches the step of executing Python script `python3 -m unittest discover -s uat/` probably since **the Docker container is never stopped**

**Question: how to make the `python3` command work in effect and then stop the Docker container also? or is using one Docker instance started in the previous job step impossible at all?**

Comment: You need to publish the corresponding ports on the container for the unit tests to communicate with the server (ex. `docker run -p 8080:8080 ...`). Also note that new WildFly builds are now published on [Quay.io](https://quay.io/repository/wildfly/wildfly), with the updated docs.

Comment: @CameronRodriguez Thanks a lot for your comment. But atm the problem is that the command `python3 -m unittest discover -s cat/` is not executed at all since it got stuck up in the previous step `Start Wildly container for integration test` and never terminates

Comment: Ah, I see. Since the WildFly image isn't really designed to run other programs on it, you'll likely have better luck with a [composite action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-action) that builds and launches the image, rather than the container-specific action.

Comment: @CameronRodriguez I didn't mean run `python3` on the *Wildfly* Docker container, but just would like to run the `python3` command outside, but the `python` code send http request to the Docker container

Comment: @CameronRodriguez today I tried `using:'composite' , but since Docker is still needed, `using:`'docker'` is compulsory as well. This is violent against the syntax of the `action.yml`

Comment: Yeah, what I mean is that WildFly's container prints logs to STDOUT as long as it runs, so the step never "completes" until the server is run down. You can use a composite action to build and run the Docker image from Bash (so `docker build -t wfly-test . && docker run -dp 8080:8080 wfly-test:latest`), follow up with your Python step as-is, and then include a final composite action to stop and delete the container.

Comment: The [Docker action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-docker-container-action#creating-an-action-metadata-file) is intended for passing arguments to the container (which doesn't apply in your case), and [workflow containers](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idcontainer) are meant for running steps in a container, so there isn't really an elegant solution in this case, short of attempting to run WildFly as a background image in the container.